# HorizontalListView with RemoteImageView

Tags: android, gallery, horizontallist, droid-fu, webimage

Hi I am trying to use `HorizontalListView` by **dev-smart** ([from here](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34)) with each entry showing image fetched from the web using `RemoteImageView` by **käppler** ignition library ([from here](https://github.com/kaeppler/ignition)).

There is an issue that makes the image not loaded at all in the `HorizontalListView` (not even the progress spinner shown). I'm sure that the problem is not with my `adapter` since if I change the `RemoteImageView` by default `ImageView`, I can get the image shown in the list.

Anyone has any idea how to fix this? Or is there any other implementation of `horizontalListView`?

Comment: I'm using `WebImageView` instead of `RemoteImageView`, and I have the exact same problem.
I would also appreciate some hint also.
P.S.- The `HorizontalListView` from **dev-smart** has no activity since 2 years ago, so I'm not confident this is a problem that is going to be solved so soon.